# I can't seem to be able to make a hittable image (tries to make image a function)

Tags: javascript, image, p5.js

so I have been trying to make an aim trainer with javascript p5, but when I try to load in an image as an randomly shootable target it doesnt seem to let me click the image. I dont really understand why since I am new to coding. also the clicking on the normal ellipse doesnt work. but right now thats not what I am worrying about.

error:
TypeError: img2 is not a function
at draw (/script.js:82:5)
at p5._main.default.redraw (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.3.1/lib/p5.js:70718:27)
at _draw (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.3.1/lib/p5.js:63058:25)

```
let MENU = 0;
let img;
let img2; // -------------------------------------------
var life = 3;
var score = 0;
var shootFail = 0;
var x, y;
const radius = 20;
function preload() {
  img = loadImage('GAME_logo.png')
  img2 = loadImage('durtburd.png')// -----------------------------------
}
function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 600);
    
}
  function mousePressed() {
  // Check if mouse is inside the circle
  var d = dist(mouseX, mouseY, x, y);
  if (d < radius) {
    newCircle();
    score++;
  }
     console.log("text", mousePressed)
}

function newCircle() {
  x = random(750);
  y = random(550);
}

setInterval(newCircle, 1000);
function draw() {
  cursor('test2.cur');
  background(225);
  // maakt start reflex knop
  fill('darkgray');
  rect(50, 50, 200, 75);
  // maakt instructions knop
  fill('darkgray');
  rect(50, 200, 200, 75);
  // maakt start tracking knop
  fill('darkgray');
  rect(50, 350, 200, 75);
  //maakt de teksten aan
  textSize(25);
  fill('white');
  text('START', 60, 90); //start text
  text('REFLEX', 60, 110); // reflex text
  textSize(24);
  text('INSTRUCTIONS', 60, 250); // instuctions text
  textSize(25);
  text('START', 60, 390); // start text
  text('TRACKING', 60, 410); // tracking text
  scale(0.9)
  image(img, 320, 50, 530, 520) // loads the logo

  if (MENU == 1) { // START GAME
    noStroke();
    background(35, 39, 42);
    fill('white');
    textSize(20);
    text('Press escape to return to MENU', 500, 30);
    textSize(60);
    fill('red');
    text('♥'.repeat(life), 400, 300);
    fill('white');
    textSize(30);
    text("Score: " + score, width/2, height/2 + 40);
    text("Misses: " + shootFail, width/2, height/2 + 65);
    //ellipse(x, y, radius*2, radius*2);
    image(img2,x, y); //dont know how to implement this------------------------------------
    if (keyIsDown(27)) {
      MENU = 0;
    }
```

Comment: The issue you're describing is not reproducible, nor is any defect apparent, given the code you have posted. Please try to follow the guidelines described here when posting questions on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example